# How to count how many times certain values appear in a table in SQL and return that number in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I've used the COUNT function to determine how many rows there are in a table or how often a value appears in a table.

However, I want to return the 'count' for multiple values in a table as a seperate column.

Say we a have a customer table with columns; Customer ID #, Name, Phone Number.
Say we also have a sales table with columns: Customer ID, Item Purchased, Date

I would like my query to return a column for customer ID and a column for # of times that customer ID appeared in the sales table.  I would like to do this for all of my customer IDs at once--any tips?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select   customer_id,
         count(*)
from     sales  
group by customer_id
```

This will return a row by customer ID with the count of how many matching items.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `GROUP BY`

```
Select Count(*), CustomerID
from Sales
GROUP BY CustomerID
```